# Write fpos_t to disk

Tags: c++, c, io, hpc

I have the following question: In parts of my software (mostly C++) I rely on reading precalculated binary data from a file to be used in a numerical simulation. This files can be quite big (like 32GB and upwards).

At the moment I read in the data with fread and store/navigate some important filepostions with **fgetpos/fsetpos**.

Mostly my software runs on HPC-Clusters and at the moment I'm trying to implement a restart feature in case I run out of Wallclocktime so that I can resume my calculations. To that end I dump a few key parameters in a binary file and would also need to store the position of my fileptr prior to abortion of my code.

So I checked around through the forum and I'm not quite sure whats the best solution to do this. 
I guess I can't just write the whole **fpos_t** struct to disk as this can produce nonsense when I read it in again. ftell is limited to 2GB files if I'm correct?

Would ftello be a better option? Is this compatible with different compilers and OS(like intel, cray and so on)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered memory-mapping the file? That way, you'd just have an unsigned integer with the size of a pointer (`uintptr_t`). In addition, all features of streams (buffers, codeset conversions) would not be used and you would also avoid one copy of the data to a local buffer, possibly increasing performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I haven't considered it yet! However, I'm bound to use the basics like fread, fwrite, fseek, ftell and so on for portability with other parts of the code, since my code is only a small part of a bigger software project.

Comment: For sure `ftello` is not (quite) standard, but there is also `_ftelli64` (and related seek functions) on other systems, so maybe a wee bit of platform-specific code (using `#ifdef … #else … #endif` blocks) may be required?

Comment: You marked it c++, so can you use std::ifstream ? (why not ? why are you not using that already ?) can you `boost` in the project ? I guess not. If writing a library, multitargeting, etc. you may be faced with making your own "source control" ei. #ifdef, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! I can't really use ifstreams as the software project has wrappers that wrap fread, ftell and stuff also for usage with the zlib. So according to the fileextension files are written to with fwrite or gzwrite. Same for all the other f's. I think i will give it a try with ftello and compile the code with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64